# Program never enters while loop

Tags: python

I'm trying to count the number of times a substring consecutively repeats in a string. For example, if AAA is present, it may repeat 4 times in one place and 9 times in another, in the same long string. My code outputs empty lists. This is the relevant part shown:

```
# for every sequence
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(len(deoxy)):
        k = j + len(seq[i])
        
        # if every 4 chars are not equal to required sequence
        if deoxy[j:k] != seq[i]:
            pass            
        elif deoxy[j:k] == seq[i]:
            p = j
            l = j + len(seq[i])
            points = 0
            while deoxy[p:l] != seq[i]:
                points += 1
                print(deoxy[p:l])
                p += len(seq[i])
                l += len(seq[i])
            if points >= 1:
                lists[i].append(points)
        else:
            pass

print(lists)
```

Comment: Why should it enter the `while` loop? See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Please add values for `deoxy` and `seq` to your example. Otherwise we won't be able to run this. At the moment I could tell you that it doesn't even enter the second `for` loop because `deoxy` is an empty list.

Comment: There's no point in the final `else:` block. Either it's equal or not equal, what other possibility is there? All you really need is a single `if deoxy[j:k] == seq[i]:` condition.

Comment: Please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to trace through the logic of your code. Also make sure that you are able to *explain* your intended algorithm in plain English.

Comment: It looks to me like the `while` condition is backwards. It should be `while deoxy[p:l] == seq[i]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `while` condition is backwards. You should repeat the loop as long as you find a matching substring. You're never going into the loop because you're looking at a matching substring (that's what the `elif` condition tests).

You also have lots of unnecessary code. If you don't want to do anything when you don't find a match, you don't need that `if` condition.

And `points` will always be at least 1, because you're starting from a known match. So you don't need to test `if points >= 1:`.

```
# for every sequence
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(len(deoxy)):
        k = j + len(seq[i])
        
        if deoxy[j:k] == seq[i]:
            p = j
            l = k
            points = 0
            while deoxy[p:l] == seq[i]:
                points += 1
                print(deoxy[p:l])
                p += len(seq[i])
                l += len(seq[i])
            lists[i].append(points)

print(lists)
```